# Epoch time to seconds from now

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Kind of going in circles here. I have an API returning the unix timestamp. I need to convert that in seconds from now to the actual date. For example, if given an epoch time of `1634578318`, I need the number of seconds for the difference between now and `Monday, October 18, 2021 5:31:58 PM`.

No need to format it beyond that. I'm stumbling on a lot of posts and documentation regarding human readable format, but just need the seconds.

Comment: Just get the current epoch time in seconds, and subtract.

Comment: `new Date() / 1000 - 1634578318` or `Date.now() / 1000 - 1634578318` as per [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)

Comment: @ChrisG Perfect. I was dancing around this in my trial and errors, but this did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the unix time from

`moment().unix()`

Then substract it from the timestamp of your api call - that's it.

See https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp/